# Insert two date variables into startDate and endDate fields in the table

Tags: php, mysql

I want to insert 2 date variables into startDate and endDate fields in the table.
First is $today, next is $today plus $duration.

I have this piece of code which used to work before, but now it does not work 
again.

```
require_once('connection/config.php');
$today = date("y:m:d"); //get today's date
$duration = 14; //get duration

$sql_insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO adverts (cust_id, startDate, endDate)VALUES('".$today."', (CURDATE()- WeekDay(CURDATE()) +'".$duration."')");

if($sql_insert){echo 'Successful';}else {echo 'Failed';}
```

This code worked previously. But now, it's not working again.
It does the insert and returns the result for the endDate as '0000-00-00'.

I do not know why it is returning '0000-00-00'.
Please help me.
Thank you all.

Comment: Look at the documentation for MySQL Date/Time functions. There are functions for adding dates. You don't just use the `+` or `-` signs.

Comment: `(cust_id, startDate, endDate)VALUES('".$today."', (CURDATE()- WeekDay(CURDATE()) +'".$duration."')`, there are 3 fields but only two values.

Comment: I know about the 3 fields and 2 values. It was an omission. I saw the omission. But despite the omission, the curdate - weekday code ONLY works well with interval less than 14 days.

Answer (score 0):

You can't just subtract integers from dates in MySQL (that's an Oracle thing).

You need `CURDATE() - INTERVAL WEEKDAY(CURDATE()) DAY` to do what you're trying to do.

Comment: But how will it work? Now, I have a form. The form allows a user to post advert. The user will select the duration wherein his advert will run. Now, the starting date is day the user submits the form to the table - $today, Now, I want to INSERT both $today into startDate field and add the user's duration + $today to get the endDate. From your code, how do I bring in $duration? Thank you for your contribution.

Comment: Remember that, the user can pick any duration of ranging from 3 min to whatever number of days he chooses. Duration is in days.

Comment: Using CURDATE() - INTERVAL WEEKDAY(CURDATE()) DAY only works when you are adding less than 14 days. From 14 days, it does not work.

Comment: With respect, I disagree.  Try `SELECT CURDATE() - INTERVAL WEEKDAY(curdate()) DAY + INTERVAL 800 DAY` . You'll get a perfectly valid date. `TIMEDIFF()` does have a maximum result of +/- 839 hours, but that's not relevant to the present problem.